# Hello, I have a question about the compatibility of cs50.h with computers without the aforementioned library installed

Tags: c, cs50, stdio

I just completed my first working program, but it uses cs50.h . I was wondering if 1. It will work outside of the CS50 Sandbox, and 2. If it does not, would anyone be willing to explain how I would go about changing it.
I am willing to learn, say, `scanf` as I am always willing to learn. Here's what I've got so far.
Thank you!

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>  
int main()  
{  
    string one = get_string("Hi! I'm Copycat.\n");
    printf("%s\n", one);
   for(;;)  
   {
    string two = get_string("");
    printf("%s\n", two);
   }  
return 0;  
}
```

Comment: Yes it can be used if you go and get the cs50.h file and the cs50.c file and compile it and link against it, you can get them from [**here**](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/tree/develop/src)

Comment: CS50 is nothing but a set of C convenience functions and definitions (in `cs50.h` and `cs50.c`). In your case, to use it outside CS50, understand `string` is just a typedef to `char *` and `get_string(...)` is just a function that takes a variable set of arguments that it turns into a prompt using `vprintf` (similar to `printf` but taking a `va_list` as its parameter). So you simply remove the `#include <cs50.h>` line, change `string` to `char *` and rewrite `get_string()` however you like and you are good. It's all just C. CS50 just writes basic function for you.

Answer (score 0):

It won't compile. `#include <cs50.h>` will fail since that file doesn't exist.

Should we remove that line, the missing declarations from that file (e.g. `string`, `get_string`) will cause problems (compilation warnings and/or errors).

Finally, the linker will fail to find the functions provided by the sandbox (e.g. `get_string`) and fail to create an executable.

Comment: You didn't specify what problems you were having with `scanf`, so I did not address those problems in my answer.